# How do you move the shelf that is hiding a secret room?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-falskaar

I am playing the Skyrim mod Falskaar, how do I move the shelf that reveals the secret room in `Dread Aura` quest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find the solution around minute 16 in this video:

Find the note under a table which allows you to activate a pullbar nearby.

---

Old answer:

I didn't play that mod yet, but it's probably either a fake back *inside* the shelf (like the one in [Hjerim](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blood_on_the_Ice#Hjerim)) or you have to grab it like you can move items in general via [holding down the the activate/use button](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Controls#General_Gameplay) (<kbd>E</kbd> on PC), a severely underdocumented feature

Comment: Thanks, I will once I have some spare time. You can of course always cheat and use the construction kit to check the shelf for scripts... Or maybe you find the answer in [this video](http://youtu.be/qlXXqkUZEIs?t=16m10s) (I don't feel like spoiling the entire quest, but you probably have a better idea where to jump to in that 20min video)

Comment: You're welcome - I skimmed the video after all and found it around minute 16. Comments are usually only deleted if a) the users do so b) sufficiently many people flag them e.g. as obsolete c) after a lengthy discussion one of the participants clicks the "turn into chat" link or d) a mod goes rogue :-7

Answer (score 3):

Once in the room, looking from the entrance :

- Look under the table, you will find a note there, read it
- then just above the big chest, there is a pullbar, activate it and the shelf will open

**Important note:** ***avoid at all cost using tcl or a teleport mod*** to get at the crystal. You will get the crystal, but ***it will not be marked as found***, and no amount of using console (on PC) to change quest stages in the quest (id: fssq16) will repair. If you do that you'll be unable to complete Dread Aura and Dreams of Oblivion.

Upon completion of Dread Aura, the reward is 75 Gold from Klara, and a discount of 50% on the rooms cost at Amber Mead Inn